# Asp.net mvc4 bootstrap tab change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I can't succeed to hook an @Url.Action on the onshown event of a tab in one of my view (I want to change a property of my ViewModel on every new tab selection). Is there any trouble with this?

```
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content" >
        @foreach (var item in Model.LesCategories)
        {

            <div id="tabs-@item.Id" class=" tab-pane @item.ClasseActive" onshown="location.href ='@Url.Action("ChangeAction","Plat")'">
                <table>
                    @foreach (var plat in Model.LesPlats)
                    {
                        if (plat.Category.Id == item.Id)
                        { 
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(platItem => plat.Nom)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action <span class="caret">
                                    </span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="/Plat/Edit/@plat.IdPlats">Modifier</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/Plat/Details/@plat.IdPlats">Détails</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/Plat/Delete/@plat.IdPlats">Supprimer</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/Plat/Descendre/@plat.IdPlats">Descendre</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/Plat/Monter/@plat.IdPlats">Monter</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        }

                    }
                </table>
                <div class="espace_bas">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I edited my question and added the code of my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind onshown event like that. You have to capture tab container with jQuery and bind it with on option like shown in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs):

```
$('.tab').on('shown', function (e) {
  location.href ='@Url.Action("ChangeAction","Plat")';
})
```